# Can this jQuery code be refactored

Tags: jquery, refactoring, readability, code-readability

I am trying to improve my jQuery skill and I have this bit of code. It's basic purpose is to size and resize a background to keep it at the same height as a responsive slider, so matching the size of the window; and tracking that if it's resized by the user.

Could it be refactored better or is it good as it is.

```
$(window).load(function() {
var height = $('#display-area').css('height');
$('.skin-background')
    .css('display', 'block')
    .css('height', height);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
var height = $('#display-area').css('height');
$('.skin-background')
    .css('height', height);
});
```

Comment: Post it in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Cache elements that get used more than once
var $background = $('.skin-background');
var $displayArea = $('#display-area');

// Don't repeat yourself, put recurring actions in functions
var resizeBackground = function() {
    $background.css({
        'display': 'block',
        'height': $displayArea.height() + 'px'
    });
};

$(window).load(resizeBackground).resize(resizeBackground);
```

You should also consider to "[throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)" the event handler for the resize event, because some browsers fire *a lot* of them when resizing the window. Using underscore.js, this would then be:

```
$(window).load(resizeBackground).resize( _.throttle(resizeBackground, 100) );
```

Comment: $(window).bind("load resize",resizeBackground);

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on("load resize",function() {
var height = $('#display-area').height();
$('.skin-background')
    .css({'display':'block','height':height});
});
```

Comment: What benefit does this have? None to me, I'm sorry.

Comment: I like the `{'display':'block','height':height}`. I forgot I could do that.

Comment: I mean, that in my opinion it does not make the code any better.

Comment: Well, that is quite a difference now *after* your edit. But begging for an upvote does not work for me.

Comment: hey iam not begging you for upvote that was just a pj and your upvote don't affect me so much as in three-four days i will earn more reputation than you if stayed active

Answer (score 1):

You can use single selector for adding both events and can set multiple css attributes like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
var height = $('#display-area').css('height');
$('.skin-background')
    .css('display' : 'block','height', height);

}).resize(function() {
var height = $('#display-area').css('height');
$('.skin-background')
    .css('height', height);
});
```